# bindfs, inverse operation?

Tags: automount, umount

In my `.bashrc` I have

```
function bindfs () {
  mkdir -p ~/$1
  sudo /usr/bin/bindfs -u $(id -u) -g $(id -g) $1 ~/$1
}
```

in order to be able, as a normal user, to read, write, execute files on ext3 file systems auto-mounted below `/media/`. This works fine.

However, I would like to know the inverse operation of `bindfs`. Otherwise I cannot umount the  USB storage media before unplugging.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use umount

```
sudo umount ~/$1
```

Answer (score 8):

bindfs is FUSE filesystem and can be used from non-privileged users is

```
user_allow_other
```

is set in /etc/fuse.conf.

It's natural counter-part is

```
fusermount -u
```

that can be run by standard users, as well